# Accessing single Item/Document in Domino via URL Request

Tags: xml, json, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Getting a list of items from a View is pretty easy and also simple to parse as you can get the result as XML or JSON.

```
GET http://www.acme.com/addresses.nsf/ContactsView?ReadViewEntries
```

The problem arises when I try to fetch a single Item/Document from this list like

```
GET http://www.acme.com/addresses.nsf/ContactsView/UNID
```

It always returns a HTML Page that is hard to parse.
Is it possible to get a single item with this method (not with Access Service or Web Service etc.) that is in XML/JSON/etc. format OR is it possible to create a View that can receive and process a parameter and return the specified item? Something like this:

```
GET http://www.acme.com/addresses.nsf/SpecificItem?ReadViewEntries&fetchId=UNID
```

This way I would get the item in XML/JSON View. I just would have to define the fields the View should return.

Comment: What release of Domino is running on your server? If it's new enough, you could use the REST service URLs. See here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Document_GET_dds10&content=apicontent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not opening a view but the document with the form when you *GET www.acme.com/addresses.nsf/ContactsView/UNID*. This is why you get HTML.

You should configure a new form for displaying XML/JSON for the document.
You will have to:

1. code a new form that display the XML or JSON
2. change the Content-type of the Form (form properties) to other and specify XML or JSON
3. in the view indicate that document are "opened" with you new form (step1) by using the Form formula of the view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure how to associate the form with the view to open documents with it (step 3). Apart from that I also struggle with Step 1 as I am a novice in Domino (just need to programmatically access Domino, never used it before), but I am sure there exists some help/tutorial on this.

Comment: @Kirschi Open View properties, and check "Form formula" property. This property contains string with name of the form, which will be used to open a document in this view. Here is the image: http://imgur.com/y8Z9kJq

Comment: @RafaelOsipov thanks that worked.

I do not find the Content type Property on the Form (using Domino 9). I found help Topics but it does not like that on my System.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Best+Practices+for+Domino+8.0+Web+Application+Development#action=openDocument&res_title=07302008103854AMKMKK6W.htm&content=pdcontent

Comment: @Kirschi check the second tab of Form properties dialog. Check this picture: http://imgur.com/s4nfvzA , For JSON set `application/json` content type as it is show on the picture.

Comment: Sorry I was away! I vote up for @RafaelOsipov that assisted kirschi